# Existentials vs Covariance in Scala

Tags: scala, covariance, existential-type

Consider the two codes below. They accomplish the same goal : only such `A[T]`-s can be stored in the `Container` where `T` extends `C`

However they use two different approaches to achieve this goal :

1) existentials

2) covariance

I prefer the first solution because then `A` remains simpler. Is there any reason why I ever would want to use the second solution (covariance) ?

My problem with the second solution is that it is **not natural** in the sense that it should not be `A`-s responsibility to describe what I can store in a Container and what not, that should be the Container's responsibility. The second solution is also **more complicated** once I want to start to operate on `A` and then I have to deal with all the stuff that comes with covariance.

What benefit would I get by using the second (more complicated, less natural) solution ?

```
object Existentials extends App {

  class A[T](var t:T)

  class C

  class C1 extends C

  class C2 extends C

  class Z

  class Container[T]{
    var t:T = _
  }

  val c=new Container[A[_<:C]]()
  c.t=new A(new C)
  //  c.t=new Z // not compile

  val r: A[_ <: C] = c.t

  println(r)
}

object Cov extends App{
  class A[+T](val t:T)

  class C

  class C1 extends C

  class C2 extends C

  class Z

  class Container[T]{
    var t:T = _
  }

  val c: Container[A[C]] =new Container[A[C]]()
  c.t=new A(new C)
  //c.t=new A(new Z) // not compile

  val r: A[C] = c.t

  println(r)
}
```

---

EDIT (in response to Alexey's answer):

Commenting on :
"My problem with the second solution is that it is not natural in the sense that it should not be A-s responsibility to describe what I can store in a Container and what not, that should be the Container's responsibility."

If I have `class A[T](var t:T)` that means that I can store only `A[T]`-s and not ( `A[S]` where `S<:T` ) in a container, in any container.

However if I have `class A[+T](var t:T)` then I can store  `A[S]` where `S<:T`  as well in any container.

So when declaring `A` either to be invariant or covariant I decide what type of A[S] can be stored in a container (as shown above), this decision takes place at the declaration of `A`.

However , I think, this decision should take place, instead, at the declaration of the container because it is container specific what will be allowed to go into that container, only `A[T]`-s or also `A[S]` where `S<:T`-s.

In other words, changing the variance in `A[T]` has effects globally, while changing the type parameter of a container from `A[T]` to `A[_<:S]` has a well defined local effect on the container itself. So the principle of "changes should have local effects" here favors the existential solution as well.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case `A` is simpler, but in the second case its clients are. Since there is normally more than one place where you use `A`, this is often a worthwhile tradeoff. Your own code demonstrates it: when you need to write `A[_ <: C]` in the first case (in two places), you can just use `A[C]` in the second one.

In addition, in the first case you *can* write just `A[C]` where `A[_ <: C]` is really desired. Let's say you have a method

```
def foo(x: A[C]): C = x.t
```

Now you can't call `foo(y)` with `y: A[C1]` even though it would make sense: `y.t` does have type `C`.

When this happens in your code, it can be fixed, but what about third-party?

Of course, this applies to the standard library types as well: if types like `Maybe` and `List` weren't covariant, either signatures for all methods taking/returning them would have to be more complex or many programs which are currently valid and make perfect sense would break.

> it should not be A-s responsibility to describe what I can store in a Container and what not, that should be the Container's responsibility.

Variance isn't about what you can store in a container; it is about when `A[B]` is a subtype of `A[C]`. This argument is a bit like saying that you shouldn't have `extends` at all: otherwise `class Apple extends Fruit` allows you to store an `Apple` in `Container[Fruit]`, and deciding that is `Container`'s responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "In addition, if you forget to use the correct existential in just one method, any other place which calls it can't use the existential type either (without unsafe unchecked casts). " Could you please give a simple example on this ? I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: "In the first case A is simpler, but in the second case its clients are. " How is it simpler for the clients ? I don't get it, could you please give an example ?